# Citrus vs Mockito

Tags: citrus-framework

I have recently come across the Citrus framework and was trying to use it.
But I found I can use Mockito as well in mocking the external service to do some Integration testing of my code.

What are specific advantages of using Citrus over Mockito?

Answer (score 3):

I have recently come across the Lasagne and was trying to eat it. But I found I can use Pizza as well in eating at the dinner to do some food filling of my stomach.

What are the specific advantages of eating Lasagne over Pizza?

---

Do you get my point here? Your question is way too generic to get a good answer as you always need to decide based on the use case and what you want to do. Besides that Mockito and Citrus are not really competitors in my opinion as they have completely different focus.

Mockito and Citrus both are test frameworks, right but they have completely different goals in testing your software.

Mockito is used in unit testing with a more deep insight of classes and methods used so you can create a level of abstraction when testing a piece of your code. Citrus has focus on integration testing with messaging interfaces involved where your application under test is deployed somewhere in a shippable state and messages do really go over the wire.

At the moment you are doing unit testing not integration testing. Which is great! You need a lot of unit tests and Mockito is a really good choice to help you there. At some point you may want to test your software with focus on integration with other components in a production-like environment with completely different focus (non-functional requirements, deplyoment, configuration, messaging, security and so on). This is the time to go for integration testing to make sure that you meet the interfaces to other components and to make sure that others can call your services in a well designed way.

Which part of the testing train you need and which part you may want to stress in your project is totally based on the requirements and your software architecture.

Long sentence short I would recommend that you go three steps backwards in order to clarify what you want/need to test in your application and then pick the tools that help you to reach that goals.

Comment: What I was trying to do is to unit test a Java program which was interacting with many external services (soap and rest services). So was looking for some advises here for which framework suite better here.

Comment: There is also another use case where I want to unit test oracle osb projects as well. Not sure mockito will come useful here.